# Why would a motherboard suddenly stop working?

Tags: boot, motherboard

Yesterday I bought a new MSI H97M-G43. It ran perfectly last night and this morning, so I left my computer on and left the house. When I returned, about 6 hours later, the computer was turned off and wouldn't turn back on. The motherboard would only show a blue LED that MSI describes as the 'diagnostic light'.

After about 3 hours of troubleshooting (removing each component, ensuring each cable was properly connected), I removed the motherboard from the case, placed it on a cardboard box, and tried once more. I then restored the CMOS both by using a jumper and removing and reinstalling the battery. It still didn't work, so I transferred all of my components to my old motherboard, and it turned on.

I installed my old motherboard back into the case and everything is fine.

I've come to the conclusion that it's not a components or CMOS problem, and the motherboard definitely isn't shorting. I assume it's not a component compatibility problem; the compents all seem compatible, and as I understand the computer wouldn't boot in the first place if this was the issue.

What other explanations are left for why the motherboard won't work? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are my specs:

> Intel Core i3 4170
>
> Crucial 8Gb PC3-12900 Unbuffered
>
> Gigabyte R7 250 2GB
>
> Corsair 550W
>
> Current working motherboard is an ASROCK H81M-ITX

Comment: Any number of things could have gone wrong, most couldn't be avoided so I won't bother listing them, this is precisely the reason warranties exist.  Electronics are complicated, they can work for 5 minutes without a problem, then suddenly just fail for no apparent reason.  Without a schematic for the motherboard ( which you will not be able to find ) it will be impossible to find the short, even if you had that, given how those boards work its very likely its an internal short within the board and if that is the case it would be impossible to fix even for MSI

Comment: I agree with Ramhound. And to sum it up: just apply for the warranty and get a new motherboard. You may have to pay for shipping, but thats it.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for failures of motherboards are broken capacitors. There is a visual way of checking this: look for swollen capacitors on the board. They are swollen on their top.

There are motherboards with better capacitors - check the motherboard description for "durable capacitors", "Japanese capacitors", "Capacitors with longer life" or something...

You could see what a swollen capacitor looks like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#/media/File:Defekte_Kondensatoren.jpg

Comment: I believe the English word is 'capacitor' - hadn't heard anyone call them condensers before.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much for your note, @Jeeva. The answer is corrected

Comment: Can I ask which language condenser is used in? Googling hasn't helped much, but has shown that it's frequently used enough that Google corrects it for me.

Comment: In my language - Bulgarian. I suppose it is this say in Russian too :)

Comment: @Jeeva I've only heard the term a few times and almost always it was my grandfather that used it. I haven't been able to find any sources on the etymology on the word _condenser_ in this context. A question for [Electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: "A capacitor (originally known as a condenser) is ..." Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor

Comment: It looks like the motherboard mentioned in the OP uses 100% solid capacitors and not the liquid ones that are normally affected by this issue. Most other recent motherboards are the same